# Attribute Error when running a Pytorch neural network in Spyder

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, spyder, attributeerror

I tried to run a neural network to learn more about categorical embedding (the exaplanation of the neural network code is here https://yashuseth.blog/2018/07/22/pytorch-neural-network-for-tabular-data-with-categorical-embeddings/) but Spyder gives AttributeError after trying to run the loop in the end.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
> exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
> File "C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
> self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'TabularDataset' on <module '**main**' (built-in)>

My understanding is that this comes from Spyder having issue with multiprocessing functionality.

I have tried, as some answers suggested, to wrap everything that is not in a class or def in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

but that did not seem to help, the error still comes up.

I also tried to import multiprocess package instead of multiprocessing but that did not help. I guess I would need to go and change the line in spawn.py file, but not sure how exactly.

The issue is that on my current PC I only have Spyder. I tried to run the same code on another dataset on my personal PC at home with Pycharm and it worked alright, with no errors at all.

Does anyone know how can I resolve the issue in Spyder?

The code for the neural network that I used is here:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class TabularDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, data, cat_cols=None, output_col=None):
    """
    Characterizes a Dataset for PyTorch

    Parameters
    ----------

    data: pandas data frame
      The data frame object for the input data. It must
      contain all the continuous, categorical and the
      output columns to be used.

    cat_cols: List of strings
      The names of the categorical columns in the data.
      These columns will be passed through the embedding
      layers in the model. These columns must be
      label encoded beforehand. 

    output_col: string
      The name of the output variable column in the data
      provided.
    """

    self.n = data.shape[0]

    if output_col:
      self.y = data[output_col].astype(np.float32).values.reshape(-1, 1)
    else:
      self.y =  np.zeros((self.n, 1))

    self.cat_cols = cat_cols if cat_cols else []
    self.cont_cols = [col for col in data.columns
                      if col not in self.cat_cols + [output_col]]

    if self.cont_cols:
      self.cont_X = data[self.cont_cols].astype(np.float32).values
    else:
      self.cont_X = np.zeros((self.n, 1))

    if self.cat_cols:
      self.cat_X = data[cat_cols].astype(np.int64).values
    else:
      self.cat_X =  np.zeros((self.n, 1))

  def __len__(self):
    """
    Denotes the total number of samples.
    """
    return self.n

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    """
    Generates one sample of data.
    """
    return [self.y[idx], self.cont_X[idx], self.cat_X[idx]]



import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class FeedForwardNN(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, emb_dims, no_of_cont, lin_layer_sizes,
               output_size, emb_dropout, lin_layer_dropouts):

    """
    Parameters
    ----------

    emb_dims: List of two element tuples
      This list will contain a two element tuple for each
      categorical feature. The first element of a tuple will
      denote the number of unique values of the categorical
      feature. The second element will denote the embedding
      dimension to be used for that feature.

    no_of_cont: Integer
      The number of continuous features in the data.

    lin_layer_sizes: List of integers.
      The size of each linear layer. The length will be equal
      to the total number
      of linear layers in the network.

    output_size: Integer
      The size of the final output.

    emb_dropout: Float
      The dropout to be used after the embedding layers.

    lin_layer_dropouts: List of floats
      The dropouts to be used after each linear layer.
    """

    super().__init__()

    # Embedding layers
    self.emb_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Embedding(x, y)
                                     for x, y in emb_dims])

    no_of_embs = sum([y for x, y in emb_dims])
    self.no_of_embs = no_of_embs
    self.no_of_cont = no_of_cont

    # Linear Layers
    first_lin_layer = nn.Linear(self.no_of_embs + self.no_of_cont,
                                lin_layer_sizes[0])

    self.lin_layers = nn.ModuleList([first_lin_layer] + [nn.Linear(lin_layer_sizes[i], lin_layer_sizes[i + 1]) for i in range(len(lin_layer_sizes) - 1)])
    
    for lin_layer in self.lin_layers:
      nn.init.kaiming_normal_(lin_layer.weight.data)

    # Output Layer
    self.output_layer = nn.Linear(lin_layer_sizes[-1],
                                  output_size)
    nn.init.kaiming_normal_(self.output_layer.weight.data)

    # Batch Norm Layers
    self.first_bn_layer = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.no_of_cont)
    self.bn_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.BatchNorm1d(size)
                                    for size in lin_layer_sizes])

    # Dropout Layers
    self.emb_dropout_layer = nn.Dropout(emb_dropout)
    self.droput_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Dropout(size)
                                  for size in lin_layer_dropouts])

  def forward(self, cont_data, cat_data):

    if self.no_of_embs != 0:
      x = [emb_layer(cat_data[:, i])
           for i,emb_layer in enumerate(self.emb_layers)]
      x = torch.cat(x, 1)
      x = self.emb_dropout_layer(x)

    if self.no_of_cont != 0:
      normalized_cont_data = self.first_bn_layer(cont_data)

      if self.no_of_embs != 0:
        x = torch.cat([x, normalized_cont_data], 1) 
      else:
        x = normalized_cont_data

    for lin_layer, dropout_layer, bn_layer in\
        zip(self.lin_layers, self.droput_layers, self.bn_layers):
      
      x = F.relu(lin_layer(x))
      x = bn_layer(x)
      x = dropout_layer(x)

    x = self.output_layer(x)

    return x

categorical_features = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]
output_feature = ["output"]
data = data[output_feature + categorical_features + ["cont1", "cont2"]].copy().dropna()
    

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoders = {}
for cat_col in categorical_features:
    label_encoders[cat_col] = LabelEncoder()
    data[cat_col] = label_encoders[cat_col].fit_transform(data[cat_col])
    
dataset = TabularDataset(data=data, cat_cols=categorical_features,output_col=output_feature)

batchsize = 256
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batchsize, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

cat_dims = [int(data[col].nunique()) for col in categorical_features]

emb_dims = [(x, min(50, (x + 1) // 2)) for x in cat_dims]


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = FeedForwardNN(emb_dims, no_of_cont=2, lin_layer_sizes=[50, 100],
                          output_size=1, emb_dropout=0.04,
                          lin_layer_dropouts=[0.001,0.01]).to(device)

import tqdm
no_of_epochs = 5
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
for epoch in tqdm.tqdm(range(no_of_epochs)):
      for y, cont_x, cat_x in dataloader:

        cat_x = cat_x.to(device)
        cont_x = cont_x.to(device)
        y  = y.to(device)

        # Forward Pass
        preds = model(cont_x, cat_x)
        loss = criterion(preds, y)

        # Backward Pass and Optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the code using the console namespace instead of an empty one (to try to preserver the `TabularDataset` definition). For that you need to check the option `Run in Console's namespace instead of an empty one` in the preferences dialog: menu `Tools > Preferences` (or the  button to show the dialog) and `Run > General settings > Run in Console's namespace instead of an empty one`.

Comment: I just tried that but with no success. That error is still showing up.

Comment: My guess is that when importing `Dataloader` `multiprocessing.Pool` is getting imported too. Maybe moving the import for `Dataloader` after the `TabularDataset` definition could help

Comment: Tried that as well but still getting the error. But when running the script directly from the Terminal it works alright. The issue seems to be with the IPython interpreter of Spyder.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I think you can face some problems when running things that depend on the `multiprocessing` module when using then IPython Console as referenced here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1900 . As a workaround maybe you could try to set the config to run the file to use an external console: `Run > Configuration per file..` and check `Execute in an external system terminal` and `Interact with the Python console after execution`